# Картинки перестали загружаться из админки

Tags: modx

Почему картинки перестали загружаться из админки?
Начал дублироваться url картинки. Как это исправить?
Если открыть страницу редактирования существующего товара, то картинки товара нет, но во фронтенде старые картинки есть.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если загрузить новую картинку в новый товар, то в админке картинку товара видно, а на сайте во фронтенде не видно. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

url новой картинки такой: `/assets/images//assets/noimage_300x0_d93.jpg`
Подскажите пожалуйста, где может быть нарушен url?

Comment: Он как бы уже наружен, откуда второй assets в пути? Смотрите на структуру папок на сайте и что вам админка выдает, анализируйте, исправляйте пути в настройках (вот только где, я уже не помню).

Comment: @DaemonHK, я структуру папок не менял, менял только некоторые js и css файлы, чтобы минимизировать их, а также перенёс стили и скрипты в футер из шапки. Есть ли ещё варианты из-за чего может быть поломан url?

Comment: а вы проверяли соответсвие путей на страницах и реальное расположение папок? все таки с этого лучше начать

Comment: @DaemonHK, кстати в админке есть такая структура:http://clip2net.com/s/3QoKsHY , т.е. в код главной страницы можно добраться как через `Filesystem`, так и через `Templates`. Если зайти в `Filesystem`, то там показывается вся структура файлов и папок сайта, а если зайти в `Templates`, то там только страницы шаблона. Я редактировал только в папке `Templates`. Могло ли это как-то отразиться на url ?

Comment: Похоже на то, потому что меня смущает `/assets` перед изображением, его там не должно быть по идее